# Pass me the almond cookie V/s Pass me an almond cookie

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Sentence:Pass me the almond cookie.
Why does this sentence not framed like -"Pass me an almond cookie"
IS it because the person wants "the almond cookie" out of all other cookies. Because the definiteness of the cookie takes precedence over "an"

Answer (score 1):

If there were several almond cookies and you wanted any one of them, you would say "pass me an almond cookie," because it does not matter to you which specific cookie is passed. If you said "pass me the almond cookie" it implies that either there is only one cookie or that only one cookie fits the description "almond cookie." You care about having one specific cookie passed to you, and are not asking for just any cookie.